# Ubuntu 15.04: Installation not possible because there is no screen

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, livedvd

I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 AMD64 on my PC (AMD CPU, SSD with Windows 10 and a Nvidia GTX 750TI). I am booting from the LiveDVD. If i do not touch a key it shows the Ubuntu logo for some time and then goes black. The monitors (I am using 2) are going black and nothing happens. After some time I am trying CTRL+ALT+F1 but nothing happens.

I rebooted and tried the bootoption xforcevesa. Now I am getting the Ubuntu logo, then a white background with my mouse and then nothing.......until I am presented with a login screen. I used "ubuntu" and an empty password. The screen goes black and I hear a sound (I am not sure if it is the login sound or the error sound) over and over again. CTRL+ATL+F1 is also not working if I am in the loop.

Anything I could try?

Thank you for any help!
Alex

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset` parameter. After installation you will need to install a proprietary Nvidia driver.

Comment: Installed Ubuntu successfuly. Thank you so much. No trying to find my way to get an actual dual boot with UEFI Windows. But I think I can figure that out :-)

Comment: Post that as an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if Pilot6 doesn't post his comment as an answer. So I will:

> Boot with **nomodeset** parameter. After installation you will need to install a proprietary Nvidia driver.